# To find $m$ of ranges of integrals

Tags: integration

If $$\int_{4}^{m} \frac{4}{x^{2}+3x-18}\,dx =\frac{4}{9}\ln6$$ and $m>4$, then how I should find the range of $m$? I tried solving for integral first. But this is ranges of $m$, is not just find a single number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{4}{x^{2}+3x-18} =\frac{4}{(x-3)(x+6)}=\frac{4}{9 (x-3)}-\frac{4}{9 (x+6)}$$
$$\int_4^m\frac{4}{x^{2}+3x-18} =\frac{4}{9} (\log (m-3)-\log (m+6)+\log (10))$$
$$\implies \frac{4}{9} \log \left(\frac{10 (m-3)}{m+6}\right)=\frac{4}{9} \log(6)\implies m= ???$$

Comment: so there is no m??

Comment: @Enjjoh You must solve $\frac{10 (m-3)}{m+6}=6$ because prof. Leibovici is too lazy to do it for you! Anyway $m=\frac{33}{2}$

Comment: !! ok yes i know now